# Understanding the output dimensionality for torch.nn.MultiheadAttention.forward

Tags: pytorch, multihead-attention

I want to implement a cross attention between 2 modalities. In my implementation, I set Q from modality A, and K and V from modality B. Modality A is used for a guidance by using cross attention, and the main operations are done in modality B.

Here is the example of my current implementation:

```
batch_size = 1
embedding_dims = 128
n_heads = 8
seqlen_A = 100
seqlen_B = 30

q = torch.randn(batch_size, seqlen_A, embedding_dims)
k = torch.randn(batch_size, seqlen_B, embedding_dims)
v = torch.randn(batch_size, seqlen_B, embedding_dims)

attn = torch.nn.MultiheadAttention(embedding_dims, n_heads, batch_first = True)

attn_out, attn_map attn(q,k,v)
```

And I notice the output dimensionality for attn_out is `(1,100,128)`, which is the same as `q`'s dimensionality, not `v`'s.

My intuition of attention mechanism is that q and k are used to extract the relationship of each other and v is the actual value. That's why I set Q with modality A, only used for guidance, and set K,V with modality B, which I mostly care about. But as `attn_out` has the same dimensionality as `Q`, not `V, I am little lost.

Is my understanding about attention mechanism wrong? And how can I possibly implement cross attention of modality A and B, where the output should be same as latent variable of modality B?

As a reference, I have a string documentation for torch.nn.MultiheadAttention.forward below.

```
Signature:
torch.nn.MultiheadAttention.forward(
    self,
    query: torch.Tensor,
    key: torch.Tensor,
    value: torch.Tensor,
    key_padding_mask: Optional[torch.Tensor] = None,
    need_weights: bool = True,
    attn_mask: Optional[torch.Tensor] = None,
    average_attn_weights: bool = True,
) -> Tuple[torch.Tensor, Optional[torch.Tensor]]
Source:   
    def forward(self, query: Tensor, key: Tensor, value: Tensor, key_padding_mask: Optional[Tensor] = None,
                need_weights: bool = True, attn_mask: Optional[Tensor] = None,
                average_attn_weights: bool = True) -> Tuple[Tensor, Optional[Tensor]]:
        r"""
    Args:
        query: Query embeddings of shape :math:`(L, E_q)` for unbatched input, :math:`(L, N, E_q)` when ``batch_first=False``
            or :math:`(N, L, E_q)` when ``batch_first=True``, where :math:`L` is the target sequence length,
            :math:`N` is the batch size, and :math:`E_q` is the query embedding dimension ``embed_dim``.
            Queries are compared against key-value pairs to produce the output.
            See "Attention Is All You Need" for more details.
        key: Key embeddings of shape :math:`(S, E_k)` for unbatched input, :math:`(S, N, E_k)` when ``batch_first=False``
            or :math:`(N, S, E_k)` when ``batch_first=True``, where :math:`S` is the source sequence length,
            :math:`N` is the batch size, and :math:`E_k` is the key embedding dimension ``kdim``.
            See "Attention Is All You Need" for more details.
        value: Value embeddings of shape :math:`(S, E_v)` for unbatched input, :math:`(S, N, E_v)` when
            ``batch_first=False`` or :math:`(N, S, E_v)` when ``batch_first=True``, where :math:`S` is the source
            sequence length, :math:`N` is the batch size, and :math:`E_v` is the value embedding dimension ``vdim``.
            See "Attention Is All You Need" for more details.
        key_padding_mask: If specified, a mask of shape :math:`(N, S)` indicating which elements within ``key``
            to ignore for the purpose of attention (i.e. treat as "padding"). For unbatched `query`, shape should be :math:`(S)`.
            Binary and byte masks are supported.
            For a binary mask, a ``True`` value indicates that the corresponding ``key`` value will be ignored for
            the purpose of attention. For a float mask, it will be directly added to the corresponding ``key`` value.
        need_weights: If specified, returns ``attn_output_weights`` in addition to ``attn_outputs``.
            Default: ``True``.
        attn_mask: If specified, a 2D or 3D mask preventing attention to certain positions. Must be of shape
            :math:`(L, S)` or :math:`(N\cdot\text{num\_heads}, L, S)`, where :math:`N` is the batch size,
            :math:`L` is the target sequence length, and :math:`S` is the source sequence length. A 2D mask will be
            broadcasted across the batch while a 3D mask allows for a different mask for each entry in the batch.
            Binary, byte, and float masks are supported. For a binary mask, a ``True`` value indicates that the
            corresponding position is not allowed to attend. For a byte mask, a non-zero value indicates that the
            corresponding position is not allowed to attend. For a float mask, the mask values will be added to
            the attention weight.
        average_attn_weights: If true, indicates that the returned ``attn_weights`` should be averaged across
            heads. Otherwise, ``attn_weights`` are provided separately per head. Note that this flag only has an
            effect when ``need_weights=True``. Default: ``True`` (i.e. average weights across heads)

    Outputs:
        - **attn_output** - Attention outputs of shape :math:`(L, E)` when input is unbatched,
          :math:`(L, N, E)` when ``batch_first=False`` or :math:`(N, L, E)` when ``batch_first=True``,
          where :math:`L` is the target sequence length, :math:`N` is the batch size, and :math:`E` is the
          embedding dimension ``embed_dim``.
        - **attn_output_weights** - Only returned when ``need_weights=True``. If ``average_attn_weights=True``,
          returns attention weights averaged across heads of shape :math:`(L, S)` when input is unbatched or
          :math:`(N, L, S)`, where :math:`N` is the batch size, :math:`L` is the target sequence length, and
          :math:`S` is the source sequence length. If ``average_attn_weights=False``, returns attention weights per
          head of shape :math:`(\text{num\_heads}, L, S)` when input is unbatched or :math:`(N, \text{num\_heads}, L, S)`.

        .. note::
            `batch_first` argument is ignored for unbatched inputs.
        """
```

it says "**attn_output** - Attention outputs of shape :math:`(L, E)` when input is unbatched :math:`(L, N, E)` when `batch_first=False`...", and I don't understand why it is not (S,E) or (S,N,E).

I ran example codes (as mentioned in the question)

Answer (score 1):

In QKV attention, the `query` is the main object we are interested in.

The `query` can be thought of as the main thing we are interested in, or the input data we want to add information to.

The `key` is sort of an "addressing mechanism". The `key` is used to calculate attention weights based on similarity between `query` and `key` items. The `key` determines how much `attention` each item of the `query` should give to each item of the `value`.

The `value` is the information we want to add to the `query`. We use attention scores from the `query` and `key` to weight and aggregate items from the `value`.

The attention result is the input `query`, enriched by information in the `value`, with the contribution of each item in the `value` weighted by the `key`.

For a more tangible example, look at the attention mechanism in the decoder of encoder-decoder transformers. In that context, the `query` (thing we want to update) comes from the decoder, while the `key` and `value` items come from the hidden states of the encoder.